# Print x86 assembly array

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a problem printing arrays in x86 Assembly.

I want to print an array one line per time with a newline at the end of every cycle but it seems like the code I am trying to use is wrong. Here it is:

```
SECTION .data 

Matrix:
db "00000"
db "00000"
db "01110"
db "00000"
db "00000",10


NewLine:  db 10


SECTION .text

global  _start

_start:


mov esi,2

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,[Matrix+esi]
mov edx,5
int 80h

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,NewLine
mov edx,1
int 80h

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

My aim in this simplified case is to print the third line of Matrix composed of five elements, a newline and exit. What I get as output is only the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that whereas this:

```
mov ecx,NewLine
```

puts the address of NewLine in ECX, this:

```
mov ecx,[Matrix+esi]
```

puts the *contents* at the address Matrix+ESI into ECX. You should be putting the address into ECX instead.

Comment: I guessed that but then how can I put the actual address in ecx and change it while I change the "counter" esi so to print different lines separately?

Comment: Perhaps something like `mov ecx,Matrix; add ecx,esi` or `lea ecx,[Matrix+esi]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why is this tagged "dos" when it's obviously Linux code? No matter, the "lea" solution MRAB suggests should work. With esi = 2, it's only going to move you to the second byte of the first line - if you want to print the third line, you want esi to be 10... etc.

Best,
Frank

Comment: I tagged it assembly,x86, forgive my ignorance, where is the DOS tag?

Comment: My mistake. Acid flashback from the 60s, I guess. :)